# Multithreading newSingleThreadExecutor Starvation Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, executors

This is straight from Java Concurrency in Practice.
The following causes a Deadlock :

```
class ThreadDeadlock {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    public class RenderPageTask implements Callable<String> {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Future<String> header, footer;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            header = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("header.html"));
            footer = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("footer.html"));
            //String page = renderBody();
            // Will deadlock -- task waiting for result of subtask
            //System.out.println("executed header and footer");
            String headerS = header.get();
            System.out.println("retrieved header");
            String footerS = footer.get();
            return headerS+ footerS;
        }
    }
}



class LoadFileTask implements Callable<String>{
    String name;
    public LoadFileTask(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        /*Scanner s = new Scanner(name);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
            str.append(s.nextLine());
        }*/
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+this.name);
        return "";
    }
}

/* Call from Main */
         private static void checkDeadLock(){
    ThreadDeadlock.RenderPageTask callable = new ThreadDeadlock().new RenderPageTask();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    es.submit(callable);
    es.shutdown();
}
```

I am unable to figure out why this causes a deadlock.
I have checked and it does.It even returns the header.get() and prints retrieved header, then how does it deadlock?

Comment: How did you run this example? And, please, provide your `LoadFileTask` source. Actually the deadlock must be in first call of `Future.get` - if you have something printed, then you executing this example in different way.

Comment: Updated the entire source. That's exactly whats baffling me, if I get future.get() for header, that's supposed to exit the header runnable, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no deadlock in your code, JVM doesn't shutdowned because it have working thread - executor thread for `exec` service(defined in `ThreadDeadlock`).
If you add

```
exec.shutdown();
```

before `return` in `RenderPageTask` then program will terminate after all tasks will be completed.

Comment: perfect.However, now the question comes, why did it not deadlock as was mentioned. Or am I missing something on my problem statement?

Comment: There is no deadlock because you run `RenderPageTask` in separate executor = separate thread. If you will use same executor(with one working thread) for `RenderPageTask` and `LoadFileTask` starting - then it will be deadlock.

Comment: Perfect, once again! Thanks a lot ice! :)

Answer (score 0):

The deadlock cause is simple: the first task submits another 2 tasks and waits them to finish, effectively blocking the single working thread of the executor and preventing that tasks from execution.

Either:

- do not ever use blocking operations in the tasks running under executor
- or use executor which adds working threads as needed

Answer (score 0):

I ran in misunderstanding with such example.
But as @ice said - you should use same executor for header/footer and RenderPageTask for deadlock.
Here is an example with deadlock:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var poolDeadlock = new ThreadDeadlock().new RenderPageTask();
    System.out.println(poolDeadlock.call());
    poolDeadlock.getExecutor().shutdown();
}

public static class ThreadDeadlock {
    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public class RenderPageTask implements Callable<String> {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Future<String> header, footer;
            header = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("header.html"));
            footer = exec.submit(new LoadFileTask("footer.html"));
            String page = renderPage();
            // Deadlock because you're using same single thread pool for header/footer
            // and RenderPageTask
            return header.get() + page + footer.get();
        }

        private String renderPage() throws Exception {
            return exec.submit(new RenderPageTask()).get();
        }

        public ExecutorService getExecutor() {
            return exec;
        }
    }
}

public static class LoadFileTask implements Callable<String> {
    private final String data;

    public LoadFileTask(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        return data;
    }
}
```